# Getting a NaN on a variable that is quite clearly a number

Tags: javascript, variables, nan

This is by far the strangest error I've ever seen.

In my program I have one variable called avgVolMix. It's a decimal variable, and is not NaN (console.log(avgVolMix) prints something like 0.3526246 to console). However, using the variable at all in an assignment statement causes it to corrupt whatever is trying to use it to NaN. Example:

```
console.log(avgVolMix); <- prints a working decimal
var moveRatio = 10 + avgVolMix * 10;
console.log(moveRatio); <- prints NaN
```

I seriously have no idea why this is happening. I've tried everything to fix it; I've converted it to a string and then back, rounded it to 2 decimal places, adding 0.0001 to it - nothing works! This is the only way I can get it "working" right now:

```
var temp = 0.0;
for(i = 0; i <= avgVolMix; i+=0.1)
     temp = i;
```

This assigns a number that is close to avgVolMix to temp. However, as you can see, it's extremely bad programming. I should also note that this isn't just broken with this one variable, every variable that's associated with a library I'm using does this (I'm working on a music visualizer). Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Edit: I'm not actually able to access the code right now to test any of this stuff, and since this is a company project I'm not comfortable opening up a jsfiddle anyway. I was just wondering if anyone's ever experienced something like this. I can tell you that I got the library in question from here: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2011/03/music-visualizer-in-html5-js-with-source-code.html

Comment: Where do `avgVolMix`come from?

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(parseFloat(moveRatio))`?

Comment: `typeof avgVolMix` shows what?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/RhAdK/

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code ?

Comment: If it's NaN it's NaN; it might just be a string that to you looks like a number. Try with typeof to be sure

Answer (score 0):

If its showing the variable value as NaN. Then try converting the variable as parseInt(); method. Hope it works. Because I also faced such problem and solved when tried it.